# Generation of new dataframe after computation of the old data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

The data frame looks like (about 10,000 timestamps)

```
Timestamp           OFR    OFRSIZ   BID BIDSIZ
2015-01-04 09:00:00 375     100     365  10
2015-04-01 09:00:33 369.9   10      365  10
2015-04-01 09:00:36 366     100     367.8 55
2015-04-01 09:00:42 367.45  30      366.4 130
2015-04-01 09:00:43 369.9   10      365   10
2015-04-01 09:00:44 365      5      367.8 55
2015-04-01 09:00:49 369.9   10      365    10
```

The requirement is a new data frame (New_df) with same timestamp and another column as depth computed as (OFRSIZ+BIDSIZ). Also can the same be applied to xts objects?

Comment: Are you looking for `dat$depth <- dat$OFRSIZ + dat$BIDSIZ`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're original data.frame is called `m1`:

```
depth <- data.frame("Depth" = as.numeric(m1$OFRSIZ) + as.numeric(m1$BIDSIZ))
depth_xts <- xts(depth, order.by = index(m1))
New_df <- merge.xts(m1, depth_xts)
```

It looks like you're using TAQ data from WRDS. You might find some interesting functions in the packages [`[quantmod]`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/index.html) and [`[highfrequency]`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highfrequency/index.html)

Comment: @kristang..yes dear..i m using HIGHFREQUENCY package

Comment: @kristang..dear I am making depth from tqdata using (OFRSIZ+BIDSIZ)/2 as high frequency package does not have direct function for the same. The tqdata is an xts containing OFRSIZ and BIDSIZ as column corresponding to a unique timestamp as rows. Can a new xts be constructed using the same timestamps as rows and Column as (OFRSIZ+BIDSIZ)/2.

Comment: I don't think I understand you're question. Do you want an xts with only the time, OFRSIZE, BIDSIZ and (OFRSIZ+BIDSIZ)/2 as columns?

Comment: @kristang..yes dear..the requirement is xts with time and (OFRSIZ+BIDSIZ)/2 as columns? I am doing it as dep_xts <- xts(TIMESTAMP = Old_df$TIMESTAMP, Depth = Old_df$OFRSIZ + Old_df$BIDSIZ) but its craeates An xts object of Zero width. Its is not showing the enteries on dep_xts object.

Comment: Just change `depth` in my answer to:`depth <- data.frame("Depth" = (as.numeric(m1$OFRSIZ) + as.numeric(m1$BIDSIZ))/2)`

Comment: @kristang..dear..i am doing like dep_xts <- xts(TIMESTAMP = tqdata$TIMESTAMP, Depth = (tqdata$OFRSIZ) + (tqdata$BIDSIZ)), where tqdata is the xts xontaining OFRSIZ and BIDSIZ. still its is showing An xts object of zero width. Please help.

Comment: You can't do that. `tqdata$TIMESTAMP` needs to be added as the argument to `order.by` which creates the index in which the data is added. Additionally, if OFRSIZ and BIDSIZ are factors, you cannot perform numerical manipulations, and you need to class them as numerics.

Comment: @kristang...I am running the following code..depth<-data.frame(date=index(tqdata), coredata(tqdata)) #converting tqdata xts to dataframe...
depth2 <- data.frame("TIMESTAMP" = depth$TIMESTAMP,"Depth" = as.numeric(depth$OFRSIZ) + as.numeric(depth$BIDSIZ))..this gives me an xts object of zero with, while depth2 <- data.frame("Depth" = as.numeric(depth$OFRSIZ) + as.numeric(depth$BIDSIZ))..gives me data frame of depth only..i require corresponding time also..Please help.

Comment: Do you want the final result to be a `data.frame` or an `xts` ?

Comment: @kristang...dear I think the problem lies in depth_xts <- xts(depth, order.by = index(m1))..as the error says  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object..I tried using depth$TIMESTAMP insted of m1 as depth is my dataframe...but in vain..depth_xts21 <- xts(depth21, order.by = index(as.POSIXct(depth$TIMESTAMP)))
Error in as.POSIXct.default(depth$TIMESTAMP) : 
  do not know how to convert 'depth$TIMESTAMP' to class “POSIXct”

Comment: @kristang..output should be xts

Comment: What are the classes of your columns in the `depth` data frame?

Comment: data.frame': 7212 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ date  : POSIXct, format: "2015-04-01 09:00:00" 
 $ PRICE : Factor w/ 472 levels "364.2",
 $ SIZE  : Factor w/ 874 levels "0","1","
 $ OFR   : Factor w/ 576 levels "365","
 $ OFRSIZ: Factor w/ 1625 levels "1","10","100",..
 $ BID   : Factor w/ 571 levels "365.15","365.25
 $ BIDSIZ: Factor w/ 1638 levels "1","10","100",..:

Comment: The principle behind `xts` is that you create a skeleton with the time-stamp as the index, and in this skeleton you put in the data you want. 
I would suggest reading these (old) slides:  http://www.rinfinance.com/RinFinance2009/presentations/xts_quantmod_workshop.pdf

Comment: Part of the problem might be you're trying to convert factors to numeric incorrectly. Unfortunately R messes up when converting factors straight to numeric values. You have to first convert to character and then numeric: `depth$OFRSIZ <- as.numeric(as.character(depth$OFRSIZ))`. I'd start off converting all of your factors into numeric values first and then see what kind of errors you're getting.

Comment: There is no variable named `TIMESTAMP` in that dataframe, `depth`. Use `depth$date` as the argument to `order.by`

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
New_df <- data.frame(Timestamp = Old_df$Timestamp, Depth = Old_df$OFRSIZ + Old_df$BIDSIZ)
```

Comment: @ctloftin..dear it is not working on xts data set. I am running= depth <- xts(TIMESTAMP = tqdata$TIMESTAMP, Depth = tqdata$OFRSIZ + tqata$BIDSIZ) It i snot showing error, but it creates xts object of zero width

Comment: depth_df <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = depth$TIMESTAMP, Depth = depth$OFRSIZ + depth$BIDSIZ)
Error in data.frame(TIMESTAMP = depth$TIMESTAMP, Depth = depth$OFRSIZ +  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 7212
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(depth$OFRSIZ, depth$BIDSIZ) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: @gauravkumar that means your OFRSIZ and BIDSIZ variables are actually factors, not numeric. Could you update your original post with a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Agree with what @josilber said about the reproducible example. For adding the two columns together, you apparently need to convert them to numeric first: as.numeric(as.character(depth$OFRSIZ))

Comment: @ctloftin and josilber- I convert them in numeric- depth$OFRSIZ<-as.integer(depth$OFRSIZ)
depth$BIDSIZ<-as.integer(depth$BIDSIZ)
depth_df <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = depth$TIMESTAMP, Depth = depth$OFRSIZ + depth$BIDSIZ), the error is coming Error in data.frame(TIMESTAMP = depth$TIMESTAMP, Depth = depth$OFRSIZ +  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 7212

Comment: When you run `class(depth$OFRSIZ)` and `class(depth$BIDSIZ)`, what do you get?